# css3 poor animation performance (Chrome only)

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, animation, css

I'm working on a site using css3 animations, it works perfectly in Safari and Firefox, but for some reason performance in Chrome is awful. (around 15 fps)

http://triple-tested.com/animations/

The animations are quite simple, basically a few large circles layered up. I've also added a few png sprite animations using javascript.

I know about hardware acceleration but I don't think that is the problem, it seems to be some quirk that is unique to Chrome. The css animations perform 'OK' alone but once I add the sprites performance drops considerably.

```
    $.fn.spriteme = function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend({ framerate: 30 }, options);        

        return this.each(function(){
            var $el =  $(this),
                    curframe = 0,
                    width = settings.width,
                    fr = 1000/settings.framerate;


            (function animloop(){
                if(curframe == settings.frames) { curframe = 0; }   
                $el.css('background-position', (curframe*width)*-1  + 'px center');
                curframe++;
                setTimeout( animloop, fr );
            })();       
        });     
    };
```

This is the code I've wrote to animate my sprites, but as I said it performs perfect in Safari and Firefox so I don't think it's the problem. Chrome seems to have an issue with animating using css alongside sprites.

I've tried everything I can find online but if anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

I'm using the latest stable chrome on mac btw (17.0.963.93)

You can see the css (using less) here btw
http://triple-tested.com/animations/css/style.less

Comment: Do you have any CSS shadows on the page? I have noticed that chrome tends to run exceptionally slowly when redrawing shadows

Comment: nope, no shadows. It's basically four or five circular images rotating.

Comment: Nice looking animation! I gave it a go using 18.<something> (beta). Still jittery. You might want to take this issue to their tracker to see what the devs have to say. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues .

Comment: Really cool animation. Performance isn't quite as bad in Chrome Canary (v. 19)

Comment: I can confirm, that performance in Opera 11.51 is under 15 fps, my hardware is Intel Core i5, 3GHz, with 8Gb RAM and build-in graphics, I don`t think that this is related to hardware acceleration at all, most probably is related to browser implementation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the replies guys, I think it is an issue with certain versions of chrome as it works perfect in the latest canary builds.

I ended up stripping back some of the animations for chrome, falls back gracefully to static images.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome is known for having issues on simultaneous transitions. One thing that might help is enabling hardware acceleration, e.g. `will-change: transform;` to make chrome us GPU for the rendering the transition.

```scss
.smooth-transition {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    will-change: transform;
}
```