# Css transition - chrome flickering

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying a simple "flip" transition on an element. It's working perfectly in Firefox, but in chrome I get a horrible flickering.

After searching and trying many things including adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to transitioning elements, I cannot find a fix.

Any ideas?

[Here's a fiddle to show what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/4p93v6oj/)

Here's the code I'm using:

```js
$('#passwordStrength__flipper').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('flipped'); // for testing, click the element
});
```

```css
.passwordStrength {
  clear: both;
  width: 99%;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  height: 240px;
  /* set viewing perspective */
  -webkit-perspective: 800px;
  -moz-perspective: 800px;
  -ms-perspective: 800px;
  -o-perspective: 800px;
  perspective: 800px;
}
.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #EAEAEA;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 1s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper figure {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper .passwordStrength__criteriaHolder {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper .passwordStrength__criteriaHolder #passwordStrength__suggestions {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #999;
  position: relative;
}
.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper .passwordStrength--success {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00C2A2;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  line-height: 26px;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
`
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="passwordStrength" id="password_popup_inline">
  <div id="passwordStrength__flipper">
    <figure class="passwordStrength__criteriaHolder">Click me...</figure>
    <figure class="passwordStrength--success">...then click me</figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, cannot reproduce the flicker in Chrome 43 / OS X…

Comment: FWIW, I got the flicker with Chrome Version 42.0.2311.152 (64-bit) on OSX Mavericks 10.9.5, but after updating to Version 43.0.2357.65 (64-bit), the flicker is gone.

Comment: I just updated as well, the flicker disappears. Haha, guess I can't try any more debugging for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` to `.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper.flipped`

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4p93v6oj/1/

UPDATE:

New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4p93v6oj/2/

As others below pointed out, the first solution does not work because the click event does not register on the element when the backface is hidden.

I modified the jquery to fire the click event on the outer element, as seen here:

```
    $('.passwordStrength').click(function () {
        $('#passwordStrength__flipper').toggleClass('flipped');
     });
```

Then, added backface visibility to `.passwordStrength #passwordStrength__flipper`

Comment: Then the click event doesn't register on the back (flipped) div.

Comment: I was toying with that idea, but I noticed that this fix to the display problem causes subsequent clicks on the element to be ignored, since the backface is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

(to [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869351/css3-poor-animation-performance-chrome-only/76485675#76485675) it here as it's a similar issue)

Chrome is known for having issues on simultaneous transitions. One thing that might help is enabling hardware acceleration, e.g. will-change: transform; to make chrome us GPU for the rendering the transition.

```scss
.smooth-transition {
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    will-change: transform;
}
```